# Finding NA in both variables in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, na

I wanna find number of NA values through `count()` function in two vectors with the same length simultaneously:

```
library(tidyverse)
list1 <-c(NA,NA,3)
list2 <-c(NA,3,4)
count(is.na(list1) & is.na(list2)) # wanna get TRUE 1 FALSE 2 as one only string contains NA values in both variables
```

It doesnt work. Following error exists:

```
  Error in UseMethod("groups") : 
  no applicable method for 'groups' applied to an object of class "logical"
```

However, I made it before learning one quite good book.

```
library(nycflights13) #data-set
flights %>%
count(is.na(arr_delay) & is.na(dep_delay))
```

Here it works. Seemingly some problem is with conversion from certain type of vector to the logical one (T or F), but I cannot figure out what exactly is.

Comment: You could just try `c(sum(is.na(list1)), sum(is.na(list2)))`. I'm still messing around with the `count` to see if I can figure out why that error is ocurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like both `plyr` and `dplyr` have a `count()` function. The `plyr` version basically says it is just a wrapper to `as.data.frame(table(x))` while `dplyr` looks like it expects a `tbl()` as the input. It appears `dplyr::count()` is what you were running above.

I would just use `table()` here, or explicitly call `plyr::count()`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
list1 <-c(NA,NA,3)
list2 <-c(NA,3,4)
as.data.frame(table(is.na(list1) & is.na(list2)))
#>    Var1 Freq
#> 1 FALSE    2
#> 2  TRUE    1
plyr::count(is.na(list1) & is.na(list2))
#>       x freq
#> 1 FALSE    2
#> 2  TRUE    1
dplyr::count(is.na(list1) & is.na(list2))
#> Error in UseMethod("groups"): no applicable method for 'groups' applied to an object of class "logical"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! Looks that I wanted to get.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `table()` which builds a contingency table of the counts at each logical value in `is.na(list1) & is.na(list2)`:

```
table(is.na(list1) & is.na(list2))
# FALSE  TRUE 
#     2     1
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks good. Its just because I am from that kind of generation who did not study classic R but started from relatively new libraries...